# Zend_Tool - What does the -p flag mean?

Tags: zend-tool

I've seen some zf commands using a flag like this: -p;

I couldn't find any information about it. Does anyone know?

Update:
I found this:

> When executing the above, it might
>   make sense to use the pretend / "-p"
>   flag first so that you can see what
>   would be done, and what tables can be
>   found in the database.

So perhaps it allows us to see the command results page per page ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will allow us to see what will the command do, without actually doing it.

So first we use to -p flag to see what it will do. Then, we process the same command, without that flag in order to actually DO the command.